# If ...or less meaning here

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, context

What does this sentence convey : "If applicant holds diploma or less, attaching high school certificate is required" Does it say: wether applicant holds diploma or lesser education proving document high school certificate is required?

Comment: Who knows? "*Holds diploma or less*" is not clear English, IMHO.

Comment: Ha ha :-) That's where comes confusion from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very poor English. But yes it means the meaning you have suggested: -

> If [the] applicant holds [a] diploma [or a] less[er] [educational
>   qualification], attaching a high school certificate is required.